# Docker stop shutdown container almost immediately despite `-t 120` setting

Tags: docker

This is how I build the docker images:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t python-trapterm .
```

and it is how I run it:

```
 docker run -t python-trapterm:latest
```

I try to stop it with

```
 docker stop -t 120 sharp_jones
```

I expect there is some 2 minutes of run time before the container shuts down. But it almost shuts down immediately? Why?

This is the output from the container process:

```
> docker run -t python-trapterm:latest
Setting traps...
 * Starting NTP server ntpd                                              [ OK ] 
2017-09-10 06:43:02,501 pid 26 tid 140693944227584 INFO     greatapp Registering signal handler
2017-09-10 06:43:02,502 pid 26 tid 140693944227584 INFO     greatapp Hello!
2017-09-10 06:43:04,507 pid 26 tid 140693944227584 INFO     greatapp Checking every 2s...
2017-09-10 06:43:06,510 pid 26 tid 140693944227584 INFO     greatapp Checking every 2s...
2017-09-10 06:43:08,512 pid 26 tid 140693944227584 INFO     greatapp Checking every 2s...
[snip]
2017-09-10 06:44:12,629 pid 26 tid 140693944227584 INFO     greatapp Checking every 2s...
2017-09-10 06:44:14,631 pid 26 tid 140693944227584 INFO     greatapp Checking every 2s...
Sending term to 26...
2017-09-10 06:44:16,537 pid 26 tid 140693944227584 INFO     greatapp Handling shutdown...15
2017-09-10 06:44:16,538 pid 26 tid 140693944227584 INFO     greatapp Checking every 2s...
2017-09-10 06:44:16,539 pid 26 tid 140693944227584 INFO     greatapp Handling shutdown...10
2017-09-10 06:44:16,539 pid 26 tid 140693944227584 INFO     greatapp Checking every 2s...
```

You can see the TERM signal is received at around 06:44:16 but the job already got shutdown around 06:44:14 but the process gets terminated after 06:44:16. There is not a 10 seconds wait.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y \
  git \
  python \
  python-pip \
  ntp \
  curl vim screen lsof

RUN mkdir -p /app

COPY ./app /app

CMD ["/app/start-app.sh"]
```

Here are the two files in my `app` directory:

**app/start-app.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

echo "Setting traps..."
trap 'cleanup_term' TERM
trap 'cleanup_kill' KILL

cleanup_term() {
    echo "Sending term to `jobs -p`..."
    kill -TERM `jobs -p`
    kill -USR1 `jobs -p`
}

cleanup_kill() {
    echo "Received kill..."
    kill -TERM `jobs -p`
}


service ntp start

cd /app
python -m greatapp &

wait
```

and

**app/greatapp.py**

```
import os
import time
import logging
import signal


LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)-15s pid %(process)d tid %(thread)4d %(levelname)-8s" \
    " %(module)-8s %(message)s"

logging.basicConfig(format=LOG_FORMAT)
LOG = logging.getLogger(__file__)
LOG.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def docker_shutdown_handler(_signum, _frame):
    LOG.info("Handling shutdown...%s", _signum)
    # sys.exit()


LOG.info('Registering signal handler')
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, docker_shutdown_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, docker_shutdown_handler)


def main():
    LOG.info("Hello!")
    sleep_time = 2
    while True:
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        LOG.info("Checking every %ds...", sleep_time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `-t` is timeout that max docker will wait for things to wrapup on its own. It is not a grace period so this is working as expected.

Comment: I don't understand why you say this. My SIGTERM handler does not anything, so the process should keep running. Then according to [the doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/#description), `-t` means "Seconds to wait for stop before killing it". The way I read it I should have 120 seconds of runtime before it is killed

Comment: Can you change `CMD ["/app/start-app.sh"]` to `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/app/start-app.sh"]` and see if you get the expected results

Comment: Thank you for including the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), they are a rare thing around here and it made debugging your container much easier. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell script is exiting. When that happens, since it's pid 1, the container is immediately exiting. You can see this if you add the following to the top of your script:

```
trap 'echo Script exiting' EXIT
```

Most likely that's a default action of the SIGKILL in bash, because it's not running any commands after that last wait. The quick way around this is to add a wait to your cleanup function so that the signal handler hangs:

```
cleanup_term() {
    echo "Sending term to `jobs -p`..."
    kill -TERM `jobs -p`
    kill -USR1 `jobs -p`
    echo "waiting again"
    wait
    echo "cleanup_term done"
}
```

Or I'd recommended just exec'ing the python script so it handles the signals directly and you eliminate bash in pid 1. The start-app.sh would then look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

service ntp start

cd /app
exec python -m greatapp
```

Comment: I used the 'exec' solution at the end! Thanks for the great answer!